# is it possible to infer higher-order function receiver type based on the parent function parameters?

Tags: generics, functional-programming, kotlin, type-conversion, type-inference

Given a function:

```
inline fun <T: Any> executeSomething(
    defaultValue: String,
    entity: T,
    maybeDefault: String = defaultValue,
    onSuccess: (T) -> Unit
)
```

I would like to infer onSuccess, receiver type T based on the parent function parameters or something like that.

This one works, compiler infer the entity receiver parameter in the higher order function onSucess as String:

```
val someEntity: String = "some text"
executeSomething("action", someEntity)
{entity -> print (entity)} //prints: "some text" - entity: String
```

Although, I'm trying to make the high order function have their type dynamically defined, conditionally based on a maybeDefault parameter value by this way enforcing a static defined type.

The function should defined like that:

```
fun <T: Any,V: Any> executeSomething(
    defaultValue: String,
    entity: T,
    maybeDefault: String = defaultValue,
    newReceiver: V = if (defaultValue == maybeDefault) newReceiver as T else newReceiver as Int,
    onSuccess: (V) -> Unit
)
```

And then the compiler should successfully, infer the staticDefineType type:

```
val someNotDefault: String = "not default"
val someEntity: String = "some text"
executeSomething("default", someEntity, someNotDefault)
{newInferred -> print (newInferred)} //prints: 1 - newInferred: Int
```

is that possible in Kotlin, which alternatives I have?

Comment: this does not work the way you'd like it to. What exactly is your use case? I'm pretty sure you can create a proper function with some generics for it

Comment: Since the type of one variable depends on a value, it requires [dependent typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which AFAIK, Kotlin's type system doesn't support.  If you give us more information about the overall algorithm you are trying to achieve, we could probably help you create a version that doesn't require dependent typing.  It seems like you might want an `Either`.